# How to stop jQuery drag/drop event on stacked DIVs?

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I know I'm missing something very basic, but when using jQuery in a situation where you have stacked "droppable" DIVs on top of each other (think nested boxes), how do you allow and accept an element drop on the top most DIV and then cancel the drag/drop event so it is not also sent to the other "droppable" DIVs below?

```
        $('#'+objectID+" .task-droppable").droppable({
        accept: function(d) { 
            if(d.hasClass("source-task")||d.hasClass("source-sequence")){ //sequences can contain both sequences and tasks
                return true;
            } //end if
        }, //end accept
        activeClass: "isDropDest",
        //hoverClass: "isDragging",

        //this is used for both drag/drop and item moves
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
            var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");

            //var sender_id = ui.sender.attr('id');
            //var receiver_id = $(this).attr('id');
            //var item_id = ui.item.attr('id');
            //var above_id = ui.item.prev().attr('id');
            //var below_id = ui.item.next().attr('id');

            //check if this is a drag/drop or a move by looking for the object class
            if(!$('#'+draggableId).hasClass('object')) {
                $('#'+draggableId).css('top', '0px');
                $('#'+draggableId).css('left', '0px');
                createObject(draggableId, droppableId);
            } else {
                //handle the move - do nothing
            } //end if

            event.stopPropagation();
        } //end drop
    }); //end droppable
```

Sorry, not enough coffee today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may need to use the [greedy option](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy)

> By default, when an element is dropped on nested droppables, each
>   droppable will receive the element. However, by setting this option to
>   true, any parent droppables will not receive the element.

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ greedy: true });
```

**[Working Example](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#propagation)**